# how to define uitableviewcells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am creating a uitableview that has two sections, section == 0 has 5 rows, and section == 1 has 1 row.

I have also declared several functions in an objective-c class that I would like to hook into each of the five rows. However I am not sure how to implement this.

I am thinking it is something like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

//---------- In here put a bunch of IF statments, declaring each cell? and linking it to
//---------- the function I have declared in the objective-c class

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the cells are setup in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Determining the function that's called when a cell is tapped is usually done in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

When setting up the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can specify the section and row using `indexPath` like this:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0){

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

        // setup this cell...

    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){

    }// ...

}else if(indexPath.section == 1){

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){

    }// ...
}
```

Do something similar in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when determining which function is called when the user taps each cell.  The relevant documentation from Apple can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Comment: Try using `enum`, it helps readability. That way, if the cells are someway static, you can do something like `indexPath.row = MyTableViewRowFruit` or `indexPath.row = MyTableViewSectionResults`

Answer (score 0):

Typically this function would be configuring the cell by pulling data out of an array, database, or some other indexed collection:

```
if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[sectionOneValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}
else if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[sectionTwoValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}
```

In your case it sounds like you want to "hook into" some other functions for the 5 rows in section 0, so you'd be doing something other than using a sectionOnValues array in the if clause. It's a little hard to be more specific without knowing what you mean to do with these functions that hook in.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, are all the cells equal, but only changing their content? In that case, you would be right.

On the other hand, if you plan on adding more Labels, images, or whatnot into the cell, then, for each different row, you would have to tweak the way the cells are being created, therefore, having to add new CellIdentifiers to avoid mixing cells, and changing the code inside the `if (cell == nil) {}` to configure each cell design.

Comment: each cell will search is requiered for a database query. But each cell will open a new tableview with a bunch of options to select.. I am just trying to figure out how to do this.. I thought I had it in my head but sat down infront of my computer today and my mind is just blank.

Comment: Sample code from Apple is usually very helpful when starting out.